# how to Restrict google maps API for particular country in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using maps API to autocomplete search result

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false
```

How can I restrict result for particular country?

Answer (score 4):

// I use this autocompleteFilter to limit search places only inside Australia.

```
_resultsViewController.autocompleteFilter=[[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc]  init];
_resultsViewController.autocompleteFilter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterRegion;
_resultsViewController.autocompleteFilter.country=@"AU";
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift you can do like.

```
  lazy var autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
  let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
  filter.country = "AU"
  autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```